# How to select some % of records from dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to select some % of records from my dataframe for my analysis, lets say 33% of record I need to select from my dataframe, which has 100 records(as an example). I need to select randomly 33 records from my dataframe. I tried "random.randint", but this is not giving exactly 33% of records, it gives approximately 33% of records only.Below is my code:

```
DF_1['ran'] = [random.randint(0,99)  for k in DF_1.index]

DF_2=DF_1[DF_1['ran']<33]
```

Do we have any other functions to get exact % of records from dataframe?. Thank you in advance. Alex

Comment: [df.sample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`randint` in a list comprehension won't guarantee an even distribution, nor will it guarantee no duplicates.

With the `random` module, you can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), which gives a sample *without replacement*:

```
from random import sample

num = int(len(Mission_3_0A.index) * 0.33)  # e.g. for 33%
indices = sample(Mission_3_0A.index, k=num)
DF_2 = DF_1.loc[indices].copy()
```

With NumPy, you can use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), specifying `replace=False`:

```
indices = np.random.choice(Mission_3_0A.index, size=num, replace=False)
DF_2 = DF_1.loc[indices].copy()
```

Most idiomatic is to use [`pd.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
DF_2 = DF_1.sample(n=num)     # absolute number
DF_2 = DF_1.sample(frac=1/3)  # give fraction (floored if not whole)
```